# A question about traveling between Schengen countries

Tags: visas, schengen

I am planning to travel from Tehran to Leipzig (Germany) and then from Leipzig to Bilbao (Spain), then I would like to get back to Leipzig from Bilbao and then get back from Leipzig to Tehran. I know that there are direct flights from Bilbao to Tehran, but it is beyond my budget. It would be much cheaper to get back to Leipzig first and then travel back to Tehran.

My question is that should I apply for a single or multiple entry Schengen visa? Can I return to Leipzig with a single entry visa?

Comment: Flights between Bilbao and Leipzig would be similar to a domestic flight in most other countries. The only immigration checks that you would be subject to are on your arrival/departure from Iran. A single entry visa would be sufficient for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple entry Schengen visa is usually issued for a long period - several months or a whole year. If your trip will last several days (a week or so) than single entry visa is enough with one condition - you **must not** leave the territory of Schengen zone. If you want to use planes during your visit your passport is needed only to check you personality.

Comment: Some low-cost airlines (f.e. Ryanair) check visas also on flights inside Schengen area.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. The flight company personnel doesn't have any authority to check visas, they only identify the passenger. It is a prerogative of border control officer.

Comment: They may not have authority to check your visa but they have authority not to board you on the plane.

Comment: (1+) To dispel the misunderstanding: Ryanair wants to have a look at the visa but they cannot stamp the passport and it obviously does not count as an entry/exit or an official border check.

Comment: ... and for this purpose "the territory of the Schengen zone" _does include_ an airplane flying between two airports that are both inside the zone, even though its flight path takes it over a non-Schengen country (e.g. Athens to Budapest, or Keflavik to Paris).

Comment: @Neusser Ryanair may check the visa, but they should not prevent anyone holding a valid single-entry visa from boarding an internal flight.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The Schengen area implies free travel of persons. That means, your passport will not be checked by immigration (you still have to identify yourself to the airline for which you may have to use your passport, but that's the airline, not a government official who can deny you access to the country). If you travel Tehran - Leipzig - Bilbao - Leipzig - Tehran, the only place immigration checks your passport is Leipzig (both on arrival and departure). Hence, your visa is only checked once, in Leipzig.